# Weird "Entry Point Not Found" error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, openal, glew

I've been using the visual studio 2008 toolset to rebuild my project for compatibility reasons, and while it works perfectly fine with the 2012 toolset (v110), after building with 2008 (v90) I got this weird message when running my program.

"The procedure entry point __GLEW_VERSION_2_1 could not be located in the dynamic link library OpenAL32.dll"

As you may know, GLEW and OpenAL are completely different unrelated libraries.

The libraries I am linking against are:

-OpenAL
-ALUT
-OpenGL
-libvorbisfile
-SDL
-SDLmain

Any idea what could be causing this weird mixup?

Comment: Have the libraries been built with the same compiler as your source code?

Comment: Some of them are precompiled binaries from the developer sites because there's no available vs2010 solutions to build from.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of interest, does your main executable and library run under the same character set?
The amount of times I have developed a static library/DLL and a main application and run into this problem beggars belief. Essentially, all projects must use the same character set (UNICODE, ANSI). Might not be your problem but I thought I would try and help :-)